# What is meant by "keeping the pipe open"?

Tags: process, pipe, cat

I've been following walkthroughs for various exploit exercises for linux applications. I understand the content of these well enough, however some refer to using cat to "keep the pipe open", e.g. [here](https://secwriteups.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/protostar-stack-6.html).

For example:

```
(python2 exploit.py ; cat) | ./programToExploit
```

What does "keeping the pipe open" actually mean in practice, and how is the pipe being kept open as with the command above?

Comment: I've always wondered this, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the difference between

```bash
echo 'ls' | sh -s
```

and

```bash
( echo 'ls'; cat ) | sh -s
```

or,

```bash
{ echo 'ls'; cat; } | sh -s
```

Here, `sh -s` will start a shell session that reads commands to execute from standard input (`-s`).

In the first example, the shell will execute `ls` and exit (since there's no more input).

In the second and third examples, the shell will execute `ls` and wait until there's no more input.  The input stream to `sh -s` was first generated by the `echo` command, but then `cat` took over.  The `cat` process will read from the parent shell session and pass commands through the pipe to `sh -s`.  If you type `ls` or any other commands (there will be no prompt to type it at), the shell will execute those commands.

This will continue until you terminate the `cat` process by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on an empty line to signal the end of input.

I believe that is what you mean by "keeping the pipe open".

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it worked as the author(s) described, I mostly just wanted to understand why it worked and why the subshell was necessary. Your answer covers this, so thanks.

Comment: This is a cool little trick!

Comment: this works but not via cron, im wondering how i can get around that

Comment: @HaydenThring If you can show what you mean by it not working in cron, and also show what you want to do, you could open a brand new question and refer to this question in it.

Comment: It launching vlc in console rc mode, and piping command too it when starts, without cat a EOF or something is sent and the console interprets that as quit, and closes the app. with cat works good, but not through cron, im guessing when cron closes after launching its sending a similar command ? its fine though im going to try a different approach with screen or supervisor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76034243/1164342

Comment: @HaydenThring As I said, please ask a new question about this specific issue.