# How is input terminated during piping though newline is not used?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, read

When I give this command:

$echo -n "Hello"

Hello$

I get the above output. This means echo -n prints the string without the terminating newline.

Now, I pipe the output to read, where the read command is supposed to keep reading until it encounters a newline.

$echo -n "Hello" | read

$

At the above command, the command prompt is returned. However, I was expecting the above command to hang as the read continuously waits for input because it didn't encounter a newline. Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: "I was expecting the above command to hang as the read continuously waits for input" Why were you expecting that?

Comment: @mosvy: Because read command is supposed to continuously read input until it encounters a newline.

Comment: Why it's supposed to do that? Both the bash's and the standard documentation are telling that it should return a non-zero status if hitting the EOF before a newline. I could just as well claim that `read` should be print an error message if instead of `echo Hello`, I'm using `echo Help` ;-)

Comment: @mosvy: I agree. My question really is though, how did the eof get there?

Comment: EOF is not something that is 'there' in the pipe. It is an attribute of the pipe itself, specifically 'this pipe has now sent you everything it ever will'. Read is too smart to keep waiting for something that can never happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you investigate the exit-status of that pipeline, you will notice that `read` returns 1:

```
$ echo -n "Hello" | read
$ echo $?
1
```

It returns 1 because it encountered an end-of-file condition and therefore failed to read more data.  The input stream from `echo` was closed because `echo` had finished its task and terminated, closing that side of the pipe.

The data read before the input stream from `echo` was closed would still be available in the `REPLY` variable:

```
$ echo -n "Hello" | { read; echo "$REPLY"; }
Hello
```

In short, `read` does not wait for further input because it noticed that the input stream was closed.

Also (tangentially) related: [What is meant by "keeping the pipe open"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348458/what-is-meant-by-keeping-the-pipe-open)

---

You may possibly come across loops like these:

```
while read variable || [ -n "$variable" ]; do
    # something with "$variable"
done
```

This allows for reading input that may not be properly terminated by a final newline character.  Without the `-n` test, and without a final newline character in the data, the last (non-terminated) line would otherwise be skipped.

The `read` utility used in this loop acts like a test.  If the input stream that the loop is connected to closes (the `read` reads past the end of the file), `read` would return a non-zero exit-status, and the loop would terminate.  With the `-n` test, it does *one extra iteration*, but that extra iteration will just confirm that, yes, there is no more data to read and now the value `$variable` is also empty.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. The question is though, how did it encounter the eof if it wasn't explicitly put there? How did the input stream get closed? Who closed it?

Comment: @user15740 The input stream was close as soon as `echo` was done. I will make this clearer in the answer.

Comment: @user15740 Also, end-of-file is a _condition_ of the input stream, not a thing that arrives over that stream.