# Keep pipe open (stdin in connected to terminal) after pipe

Tags: scripting, pipe, adb

**Motivation:** I often open a remote shell on android devices (using `adb`/ Android debug bridge), and want to write scripts on my machine (not android devices, because I have multiple) to help me when i first connect into the shell.

For example, I might want to change directory into a specific folder,
`echo "cd /storage/self/primary/Download; mkdir bobby" | adb shell`, however the stdin in immediately closed once the code is executed, and the shell is immediately closed too. I've added `mkdir bobby` just to test that the line is actually executed, and it is.

For example, the shell will automatically close in 5 seconds when I run `echo "cd /storage/self/primary/Download; mkdir bobby; sleep 5" | adb shell`. Unfortunately, a heredoc doesn't help, because it will also close the shell once the heredoc delimiter is found.

**Question:** How do I keep stdin connected to terminal after piping a command into it, so that I can type into it. This is not a challenge with `ssh`, because you can directly pass an optional command.

---

Apologies if this question has already asked, I wasn't sure how to phrase it.

Comment: Try adding ' /bin/sh -i `

Comment: Hi Angel, I guess you mean `echo "cd /storage/self/primary/Download; /bin/sh -i" | adb shell`, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. What did it do?

Comment: It immediately closed the shell after completion

Comment: I think this would be difficult in normal interactive shells if it was not for initialization files (such as `.bashrc`). I'm afraid`adb` doesn't have anything of the kind?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because `adb shell` is only interactive if no command was given. And basically I want interactive + giving a command

Comment: Does [stackoverflow.com/a/37692421/10931455](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37692421/10931455) work?

Comment: You're possibly looking for `expect`. I don't have it so can't write an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the pipe open, don't let it close.  You may do this by adding `cat` to the left hand side in the pipe:

```
{ echo "cd /storage/self/primary/Download; mkdir bobby"; cat; } | adb shell
```

The `cat` process will execute after `echo`, and have its standard output connected to the `adb shell` command, while its standard input reads from the terminal (where you may type).

As soon as `cat` terminates (by you pressing either <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to interrupt, or <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to signal end of input) the pipeline will terminate.

Note that this may not give you a full interactive shell with a prompt and command line completion or whatever other interactive features the `adb shell` command provides normally, but will let you send commands to the right hand side of the pipe.

This is similar to what's explained in [What is meant by "keeping the pipe open"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348458/what-is-meant-by-keeping-the-pipe-open)